# Custom pin on the map

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

my problem is that annotationView.image = X doesn't work, I just can't see the special pin, just purple(pinTintColor) if I remove it - it becomes red..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    for mall in malls {
        let coords = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)
        let annotation = MyAnnotation.init(coordinate: coords.coordinate, mall: mall, title: mall.name, subtitle: mall.adress)

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

and also i can't add image as accessoryview. What's the problem?

```
 extension commonMapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {return nil }

    let annotationIdentifier = "restAnnotation"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightImage
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

    }
    annotationView?.pinTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)

    annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "malls.png")

    return annotationView
}
```

Thanks for your help and excuse me for my stupidness..

Comment: The problem is that you're using `MKPinAnnotationView`. In old iOS versions, you could set the `image`, but not in recent versions. Use `MKAnnotationView`.

Comment: Also, if you successful dequeue a prior annotation view, remember to set its `annotation` in an `else` clause to your `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but I see 2 possibilities:

#### 1. If you want a purple pin with a right-image in the callout

`MKPinAnnotationView.image` is set to that of a pin, you can't change it. The code below will make a purple pin whose popup have a right-image showing Apple's HQ.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {return nil }

    let annotationIdentifier = "restAnnotation"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rightImage")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = imageView
    }

    annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    annotationView?.pinTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
    return annotationView
}
```

[image: Purple pin]

#### 2. If you want to have an image on the map

Use `MKAnnotationView` instead. You can set its `image` property to whatever you want. You can also combine with the code above to add a right-image

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {return nil }

        let annotationIdentifier = "restAnnotation"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        }

        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        annotationView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rightImageSmall")
        return annotationView
    }
```

[image: Annotation with custom image]

Comment: @Rob 1st comment: agreed. I missed that. Edited my answer. 2nd comment: I thought the OP may have wanted a purple pin so the first snippet use `MKPinAnnotationView`. As stated in the answer, the second snipper can be combined with the first snippet to make an annotation with custom image and right-image.